# useNavigate gives me blank webpage

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

App.js

```
import CreatePopBox from "./popbox";
import createGuestPage from "./guestPage";
import {BrowserRouter , Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {Routes} from "react-router"


function App() {
  return (
      <>
          <BrowserRouter>
              <Routes>
                  <Route path='/' >
                      <CreatePopBox/>
                  </Route>
                  <Route path='/guestPage'>
                      <createGuestPage/>
                  </Route>
              </Routes>

          </BrowserRouter>


      </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

guestPage.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function createGuestPage(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>GuestPage</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

popBox.js

```
import "./popbox.css";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import {Button} from "@mui/material";

export default function CreatePopBox(){

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);


    return(
       <div className= "popBox">
           <Button variant="contained" color="success" size ="large" onClick=
               {()=>{setIsOpen(true)}}>
             Continued as Guest
           </Button>
           {isOpen && <Modal onClose={setIsOpen}/>}
       </div>

    );



}
```

modal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Modal.css";
import {Button} from "@mui/material";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router";




export default function Modal({onClose}){
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const handleFormSubmit = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();

        navigate("/guestPage");

    };
    return (
        <form className="Guest" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <h1>Go to NextPage</h1>
            
                <Button variant="contained"  size ="large" id="cancel"
                        onClick={()=>onClose(false)}>Cancel
                </Button>

                <Button variant="contained"  size ="large" type="submit"
                >Continue
                </Button>
            
        </form>
    )
}
```

I create a form with a button "continue" that can redirect to guestPage.js inside the modal box. But when I use the hook useNaviage, BrowserRouter, Route, and Routes, I get a blank webpage. I am sure there is no bug in my other code, but I don't think I use useNaviage, BrowserRouter, Route, and Routes incorrectly. Do I miss anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route content should be rendered on the `Route` component's `element` prop. The only valid children of the `Route` component are other `Route` components in the case of nesting routes.

Move the routed content to the `element` prop.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<CreatePopBox />} />
    <Route path='/guestPage' element={<CreateGuestPage />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I tried this before, not working...

Comment: @Aneego I see, interesting. Can you try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Thank you. After I combine your and ivanatias' solutions, it finally works!

Comment: @Aneego `react-router-dom` re-exports all of `react-router` for convenience, so there is no need to import anything from `react-router` if you have `react-router-dom`. In fact, you can remove `react-router` from your package.json if you wanted, you only need the latter.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, make sure you import `useNavigate` hook and other `react-router` components from `react-router-dom`.

Note that you are importing `Routes` from `react-router` in your `App` component, same thing happens on your `modal.js` component with `useNavigate`.

Comment: Sorry, you mean I need to import BrowserRouter , Route and Routes in modal.js as well?

Comment: @Aneego no, I mean importing `useNavigate` hook from `react-router-dom`, not from `react-router`. Same in your `App`, import `Routes` from `react-router-dom`. Doing this and following the steps of the other answer it should work.